# How can I update this JSON object automatically using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am creating a page where users can order reports as PDF. I have tried to create it using Angular. When the user changes a report type, this is correctly updated in the debug information present on the page. However, the request for a report is sent as JSON and I would prefer if this JSON object was updated automatically as well. As it is now, I have to click on the "Create JSON" button for it to be updated.

This example can be seen over at JSFiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/HenricF/wgvd7wLx/2/

IMPORTANT
The JSON object will not only include the report type, but also a lot of other options not shown here. These options include accounts, languages and dates and the JSON object should preferably be updated whenever anyone of these are changed. I am sorry for not mentioning this initially.

HTML

```
<body ng-app="OrderPageApp">
<div id="all" ng-controller="ReportController">
    <div id="top">
        <div class="pagesection" id="ChooseReportType">
             <h3>Select report type</h3>

            <select id="dropdownlist" ng-change="setAccountTypes(chosenReport)" ng-options="report.name for report in reports" ng-model="chosenReport"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="pagesection" id="ChooseLanguage">
             <h3>Select language</h3>

            <select id="dropdownlist" ng-options="language.name for language in languages" ng-model="chosenLanguage"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="pagesection" id="IncludeHeadlines">

            <h4>Include headlines</h4>

            <input name="includeHeadlines" type="checkbox" ng-model="includeHeadlines">
        </div>
        <div class="bottom" id="bottom">
             <h4>Selected report</h4>

            <div id="reportName">Name: {{name}}</div>
            <div id="reportCode">Code: {{code}}</div>
            <div id="Language">Language: {{chosenLanguage.code}}</div>
            <div id="includeHeadlines">Include headlines: {{includeHeadlines}}</div>
             <h4>JSON data</h4>

            <input type="button" value="Create JSON" ng-click="showJson()">
            <div id="pdfData"><pre>{{pdfData}}</pre>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
    var reportTypes = [{
    name: 'Report type 1',
    code: 1
}, {
    name: 'Report type 2',
    code: 2
}, {
    name: 'Report type 3',
    code: 3
}];

var languages = [{
    name: 'Swedish',
    code: 1053
}, {
    name: 'English',
    code: 1033
}];

var app = angular.module('OrderPageApp', []);


app.controller('ReportController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.reports = reportTypes;
    $scope.languages = languages;


    $scope.setAccountTypes = function (chosenReport) {
        $scope.name = chosenReport.name;
        $scope.code = chosenReport.code;
    };

    $scope.showJson = function () {
        $scope.pdfData = angular.toJson(new CreatePdfData($scope.name, $scope.chosenLanguage, $scope.includeHeadlines));
    };

    function CreatePdfData(reportType, chosenLanguage, includeHeadlines) {
        this.reportType = reportType;
        this.chosenLanguage = chosenLanguage.code;
        this.includeHeadlines = includeHeadlines;
    };

})
```

Comment: are you talking about this ? http://jsfiddle.net/wgvd7wLx/1/

Comment: I don't get it. Why can you not just modify `setAccountTypes()` to also have in it ` $scope.pdfData = angular.toJson(new CreatePdfData($scope.name));`?

Comment: DipaliVasani yes, that is the one. Thank you.
@deitch because for each report type, there are several other options that are also included in the JSON that is then sent (such as accounts, dates and languages). I left these out of the code to make the example as minimal as possible.

Comment: @HenricF, OK so can you update the question so we understand why that wouldn't work and what needs to happen? Describe the entire flow please.

Comment: @deitch yes, I am working on it now. Sorry.

Comment: @deitch Ok, now I've updated it. This is not how the complete page looks but I hope this is enough. So the options to choose from (except for the report type) are language and headlines (as shown here), a list of accounts, and some dates. Tell me if this is not enough to present the problem.

Comment: I still don't get it. All you are saying is that there is additional data, but why can that data not be retrieved when the user selects the report type, as @DipaliVasani shows in the answer below? What additional **flow** has to happen by the user?

Comment: @deitch The expected flow is the following:
1. The user selects a report type
2. The user selects which accounts should be included (not shown in my example)
3. The user picks relevant dates for the report (not shown in my example)
4. The user selects language and whether headlines should be included
5. The user clicks a "Create report" button which sends the JSON object (that has been updated all along) to the report service.

That is why I would like the JSON object to be updated continously.

Comment: And why would you care to update it continuously? Why not just update it at the when the use clicks "Create report"? Either way, the right approach is @DipaliVasani 's below, just add `$scope.pdfData = ...` to every step.

Comment: @deitch for debug purposes I would like the JSON to be updated continously. But updating it when clicking "Create report" might work as well. I'll post a separate question for that if I can't find one.

Comment: Also, I'd be happy if the downvoter would explain his/her reasoning, so I can improve and ask better questions in the future.

Comment: If you need to update it continuously, then just add the answer below's line to each function.

Comment: @deitch I don't even have functions for most of the other options (datepickers, language etc). I don't see how I would be able to add that line to all functions? Surely there must be able to add some kind of angular watch or something to have it update automatically?

Comment: Well, how else is the other stuff getting updated?

Comment: @deitch Regular angularJS databinding using {{}}. However, this does not work for the JSON as seen in the JSfiddle for example.

Comment: I still don't get it. If there are *user* activities that cause the JSON to be updated, put the code in there; if there aren't, then you are done.

Comment: @deitch would you mind editing the JSfiddle to show how that can be done? I understand how it is done in setAccountTypes as the answer below shows but I'm not sure how to do it for the other user activities.

Comment: @henricF, can you update the post to describe the user flow in a list 1, 2, 3, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it like this (thanks to the input from deitch and Dipali Vasani):

The pdfData was updated manually as soon as any input was changed - I couldn't figure out a way to have it update automatically.

This is how I did it in HTML:

```
<input name="includeHeadlines" type="checkbox" ng-model="includeHeadlines" ng-change="showJson()">
```

And this is how I did it in JS:

```
$scope.setAccountTypes = function (chosenReport) {
    ...
    $scope.showJson();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this changes :

```js
    var reportTypes = [{
      name: 'Report type 1',
      code: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Report type 2',
      code: 2
    }, {
      name: 'Report type 3',
      code: 3
    }];

    var languages = [{
      name: 'Swedish',
      code: 1053
    }, {
      name: 'English',
      code: 1033
    }];

    var app = angular.module('OrderPageApp', []);


    app.controller('ReportController', function($scope) {

      $scope.reports = reportTypes;
      $scope.languages = languages;

      $scope.setAccountTypes = function(chosenReport) {
        $scope.name = chosenReport.name;
        $scope.code = chosenReport.code;
      };

      $scope.showJson = function() {
        var name = $scope.name;
        var chosenLanguage = $scope.chosenLanguage;
        var includeHeadlines = $scope.includeHeadlines;
        if (name == undefined) {
          name = null;
        }
        if (chosenLanguage == undefined) {
          chosenLanguage = null;
        }
        if (includeHeadlines == undefined) {
          includeHeadlines = false;
        }
        $scope.pdfData = angular.toJson(new CreatePdfData(name, chosenLanguage, includeHeadlines));
      };

      function CreatePdfData(reportType, chosenLanguage, includeHeadlines) {
        this.reportType = reportType;
        this.chosenLanguage = chosenLanguage != null ? chosenLanguage.code : null;
        this.includeHeadlines = includeHeadlines;
      };

    })
```

```html
<body ng-app="OrderPageApp">
  <div id="all" ng-controller="ReportController">
    <div id="top">
      <div class="pagesection" id="ChooseReportType">
        <h3>Select report type</h3>

        <select id="dropdownlist" ng-change="setAccountTypes(chosenReport);showJson()" ng-options="report.name for report in reports" ng-model="chosenReport"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="pagesection" id="ChooseLanguage">
        <h3>Select language</h3>

        <select id="dropdownlist" ng-options="language.name for language in languages" ng-model="chosenLanguage" ng-change="showJson()"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="pagesection" id="IncludeHeadlines">

        <h4>Include headlines</h4>

        <input name="includeHeadlines" type="checkbox" ng-model="includeHeadlines" ng-change="showJson()">
      </div>
      <div class="bottom" id="bottom">
        <h4>Selected report</h4>

        <div id="reportName">Name: {{name}}</div>
        <div id="reportCode">Code: {{code}}</div>
        <div id="Language">Language: {{chosenLanguage.code}}</div>
        <div id="includeHeadlines">Include headlines: {{includeHeadlines}}</div>
        <h4>JSON data</h4>

        <input type="button" value="Create JSON" ng-click="showJson()">
        <div id="pdfData"><pre>{{pdfData}}</pre>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgvd7wLx/3/)

This will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. As there are further options that can be selected before the report is ordered, this doesn't quite work. I will update the original question.

Comment: you can update the full code so that someone can answer correctly

Comment: @HenricF : check updated answer this will definitely help you to solve your problem.